# Swift Xcode6 UITableView Prototype Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, prototype, cell

I'm doing a project with a UITableView, but I don't know how to add data to it.

Now I'm building my first view, but something is going wrong. Can somebody help me?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit  

class WorkersListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var numOfWorkersNames = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return numOfWorkersNames.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WorkersCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell  
        // Configure the cell...
        cell. NameOfTheWorkerLabel.text = numOfWorkersNames[indexPath.row] as String
        return cell
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Now the Workers Cell:

```
class WorkersCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var NameOfTheWorkerLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to put some names in `numOfWorkersNames`. The number of cells is based on how many entries you have and from your code that is 0.

Comment: Go for a tutorial of UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify **what is the problem** and **add what data** to the tableView

If the problem is that there is only a blank view when app launched, you should add some Strings to **numOfWorkersNames**

for example: `var numOfWorkersNames = ["worker1","worker2","worker3"]`

then `numberOfRowsInSection` will get the array count which is 3, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can get its content from `numOfWorkdersNames` array

Comment: I dont want to create an Array who sets some predefined items. The workers names will be add in another view. Wit a UITextField.

Comment: So just add some data to that array. For example: you have a textfield and a button somewhere else. When you click the button it will add the content in the textfield to your worker array, so in your button click function you write `numOfWorkersNames.append(textfield.text)  tableView.reloadData()`